# I am getting a command line error while executing to publish a custom metric to Amazon CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

```
C:\Program Files\SecurityTokenService>aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "Usage Metrics" --metric-data C://Users/jbe624/Downloads/json/metric.json

Error parsing parameter '--metric-data': Expected: '=', received: ':' for input:

C://Users/jbe624/Downloads/json/metric.json
 ^
```

So I tried the below but still I get the same so anyone can advice on this?

```
C:\Program Files\SecurityTokenService>aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "Usage Metrics" --metric-data C:\Users\jbe624\Downloads\json\metric.json

Error parsing parameter '--metric-data': Expected: '=', received: ':' for input:

C:\Users\jbe624\Downloads\json\metric.json
 ^
```

Comment: As metric.json indicates  [
  {
    "MetricName": "New Posts",
    "Timestamp": "Wednesday, July 26, 2016 2:30:20 PM",
    "Value": 0.50,
    "Unit": "Count"
  }
]

Comment: tried `C:\Program Files\SecurityTokenService>aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "Usage Metrics" --metric-data 'MetricName=NewPosts,Timestamp=Wednesday, July 26, 2016 2:30:20 PM,Value=0.50,Unit=Count]'` ?